# Mysql - Order by two columns, but with one condition

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with a query in my database. Im using opencart 3.0.2.0 and in model/catalog/product.php I put this code:

```
ORDER BY p.date_added DESC, p.quantity DESC
```

I want to show me products in category, ordered by date_added DESC (newest first) but with quantity => 1 first. But on final pages, I also want to see products with quantity 0.

For example, I have 200 products in one category, 24 per page. Only 20 are out of stock (quantity = 0) and I want to see those products without stock, on last page. Also I want to be ordered all by p.date_added.

With this code (`ORDER BY p.date_added DESC, p.quantity DESC`) I see just like (`ORDER BY p.date_added DESC`). That "`p.quantity DESC`" doesn't work.

Hope you can understand me. Thanks!

Comment: If you want items that are in stock to come first, and items that aren’t, last - then that needs to be your _first_ sort criterion, not your second _after_ the date.

Comment: If I change order, then it order by quantity, and don't care about p.date_added...

Comment: You should not order by quantity, but only by whether the quantity is zero or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional ordering:

```
ORDER BY case 
  when p.quantity > 0 then p.date_added
  else null
end DESC, 
p.quantity DESC
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! I never used this "case". Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can first order by `p.quantity <= 0`. In MySQL Boolean expressions in non Boolean context are evaluated to 0 (for false) or 1 (for true). And of course 0 is before 1.

```
ORDER BY p.quantity <= 0,
         p.date_added DESC
```